# failed: ssh connection failed: 'Timeout connecting to ... (Multipass)

Tags: ssh, timeout, multipass

I got the error `... failed: ssh connection failed: 'Timeout connecting to 10.156.58.216'` when running both `multipass ls` and `multipass shell blog`.

[image]

[image]

I cannot list my instances and log in my instances.

Are there ways to solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

`multipass list` sometimes fails if run while some VMs are in the process of stopping. It may be that an instance did not finish correctly, so stop all your instances and try again.